# jQuery: Loading-image in IE dioesn't fade out sometime

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

At first, just a bit about the code:

Everytime something is loading, there will be shown a loading.icon. After all he content is ready, the icon will fade out and the content will be fade in.
Quite simple, but the IE is making some problems. Often, not every time, just the loading-image and the content will both fade in and the loading-icon will not fade out.

Any ideas how i could fix it?

Here's the code:

HTML-part:

```
<div class="loaded">
  // some content here
</div>

<div class="loader">
    // Just the loader, addet via the Html-helper of CakePHP
    <?php echo $this->Html->image('ajax-loader.gif'); ?>
</div>
```

jQuery-Part:

```
$('.loaded').ready(function() {
  $('.loader').fadeOut(fadeSpeed, function() {
    $('.loaded').fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should call .ready event for document object:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.loader').fadeOut([duration] [, easing] [, callback]);
});
```

Comment: Well, it's just a little part of my jQuery-script, of course everything is within the document-ready-function^^ Sorry, I've forgot to mention this